# Read tipsy files in Python

Tags: python, file-io, file-format

I've received a C++ macro to read and write in the tipsy file format, which I am unfamiliar with (tipsy, that is). I also received a tipsy datafile, on which I should do some research, but I would like to do that in python.

Is there a way to read (and if possible, write) tipsy files in python?

The following code gives non-readable results:

```
fid = open(FILE_LOCATION)
print fid.read()
```

Comment: Show us a sample of this file. Do you have a spec?

Comment: is "tipsy" in the site http://www-hpcc.astro.washington.edu/tools/tipsy/tipsy.html ? They supply the read/write code in the link [/pub/hpcc/tipsy_tools.tar.gz](ftp://ftp-hpcc.astro.washington.edu/pub/hpcc/tipsy_tools.tar.Z). I think it is not difficult to implement by Python.

Comment: Yes, it is that tipsy. I do not have a sample of the file, because I cannot really visualize it, like a .txt file.

Comment: Can you post a link to it?

Comment: I guess it is not public information, and shouldn't be available. The writing part goes like this:

fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, rv1)

where s is a structure with different definitions in it, and rv1 is the file

Comment: If the file format is not publiclcy specified you will have to read the C code. You can also try to wrap the C library with Python: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html#extending-index

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will look into that. I understand the C++ code and how it works, but I have to use python for the analysis. I have a now a working workaround which involves output to a normal file, and read it in the python code.